# Cufon mouse-over

Tags: javascript, html, css, mouseover, cufon

I have some HTML like this:

```
<div class="button2" onclick="">
 <div class="button_text">LOCATE STORES</div>
 <div class="button_arrow"></div>
</div>
```

I use this code for Cufon:

```
Cufon.replace('div.button2', { fontFamily: 'Bliss2H', hover: true, fontSize: '12px' });
```

My CSS:

```
div.button2 {
  color: #d79645;
}
div.button2:hover {
  color: white!important;
}
```

Cufon works, however the text color does not change on mouse-over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your buttons are links? This is the CSS for what I've got going on this page: http://ianmartinphotography.com/test-site/

My cufon buttons are at bottom.

```
h3  {color: #79868e; font-family: helvetica; font-size: 21px; margin:5px 0 0 0; } 
a:link    {color: #555055; text-decoration: none; outline:none;}
a:visited {color: #555055; text-decoration: none; outline:none;}
a:hover   {color: #79868e; text-decoration: none; outline:none;}

<div id="about"><h3><a href="about">about</a></h3></div>
```

Comment: Yes, it seems to work when I use HTML like this: <div class="button2" onclick="">
 <a class="button_text">LOCATE STORES</a>
 <div class="button_arrow"></div>
</div>
However can I avoid using <a>?

Comment: Hi Martin, If your buttons are links, why would you want to avoid the anchor <a> tag? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp

Comment: Do you have a test page that I can see to see your code in context? What would you like your buttons to do if they're not links?

Comment: I dont use the <a> tag because it does not validate with a nested h3 tag. I use onclick on the button. I dont have a testpage you can access. It's only accessable with VPN

Comment: If anyone else wants the solution, i changed my HTML to: <a class="button2" href="#">
    <span class="button_text">Button text</span>
    <span class="button_arrow"></span>
</a>

Comment: Hi Martin, I've used <div id="about"><h3><a href="about">about</a></h3></div> on my page http://ianmartinphotography.com/test-site/ and the page is passing W3C HTML validation. Is there something else that might be causing the code not to validate?  My Doctype is XHTML 1.0 Transitional. Thanks for the green check by the way!

Answer (score 2):

For performance reasons :hover is not enabled by default, which means that you’ll have to enable it separately for elements that need it. You can do this with:

```
Cufon.replace('h1', {
    hover: true
});
```

https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/styling

Comment: Bu I already did. Please check this line again: Cufon.replace('div.button2', { fontFamily: 'Bliss2H', hover: true, fontSize: '12px' });

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried #FFFFFF instead of white?

Couldn't you simply have:
    div.button2:hover {color: #FFFFFF;}

And not have !important?

Comment: I just tried with #ffffff and without !important. This is my new CSS. But it still doesnt work: div.button2 {
  color: #d79645;
}
div.button2:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}